# How can I parse command line arguments in PHP?

Tags: php, command-line

I call a PHP script from command line `$ php my_script.php --num1=124 --first_name=don`

How can I get access to *any* key value pairs passed into this script? The keys can be arbitrary, so using `getopt()` with particular values will not work.

Here is what I want access to in my script:

```
$my_args = array(
  "num1" => 124,
  "first_name" => "don"
);
```

If I use `var_dump($argv)`, I get this output:

```
array(
  [0] => "my_script.php",
  [1] => "--num1=5",
  [2] => "--num2=123"
);
```

Should I just look

Comment: @jeroen - it seems `getopt()` requires specific values in its $options argument. How can I use it to get arbitrary values?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$my_args = array();
for ($i = 1; $i < count($argv); $i++) {
    if (preg_match('/^--([^=]+)=(.*)/', $argv[$i], $match)) {
        $my_args[$match[1]] = $match[2];
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work with short options. But +1 for such laconic solution

Comment: @ymakux This is specifially designed for his argument format, not for short options.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the https://github.com/pear/Console_CommandLine composer package to let it parse the options. (I'm one of the maintainers).

An example can be found in the documentation: https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.console.console-commandline.intro.php

Comment: Please add some examples of how this tool could be used to do command line parsing. Also, it would be a good idea to mention in the answer that you're one of the primary maintainers of this project.

Answer (score 2):

I have used something along the lines of this from [PHP commandline](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php#83843)

and it will produce something like

```
array(4) {
  ["commands"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["options"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["num1"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["num2"]=>
    string(3) "123"
  }
  ["flags"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["arguments"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

---

```
function arguments($args) {
    array_shift($args);
    $endofoptions = false;
    $ret = array(
        'commands' => array(),
        'options' => array(),
        'flags' => array(),
        'arguments' => array(),
    );
    while ($arg = array_shift($args)) {
        // if we have reached end of options,
        //we cast all remaining argvs as arguments
        if ($endofoptions) {
            $ret['arguments'][] = $arg;
            continue;
        }
        // Is it a command? (prefixed with --)
        if (substr($arg, 0, 2) === '--') {
            // is it the end of options flag?
            if (!isset($arg[3])) {
                $endofoptions = true;; // end of options;
                continue;
            }
            $value = "";
            $com = substr($arg, 2);
            // is it the syntax '--option=argument'?
            if (strpos($com, '='))
                list($com, $value) = split("=", $com, 2);
            // is the option not followed by another option but by arguments
            elseif(strpos($args[0], '-') !== 0) {
                while (strpos($args[0], '-') !== 0)
                    $value .= array_shift($args) . ' ';
                $value = rtrim($value, ' ');
            }
            $ret['options'][$com] = !empty($value) ? $value : true;
            continue;
        }
        // Is it a flag or a serial of flags? (prefixed with -)
        if (substr($arg, 0, 1) === '-') {
            for ($i = 1; isset($arg[$i]); $i++)
                $ret['flags'][] = $arg[$i];
            continue;
        }
        // finally, it is not option, nor flag, nor argument
        $ret['commands'][] = $arg;
        continue;
    }
    if (!count($ret['options']) && !count($ret['flags'])) {
        $ret['arguments'] = array_merge($ret['commands'], $ret['arguments']);
        $ret['commands'] = array();
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: what is `command` how to insert it here?, also i noticed the function will do an infinite loop if i put an option with no `=` like `php my_script.php --help`

Comment: never mind i've found a fixed version https://github.com/affka/riaBuilder/blob/master/riabuilder/components/ConsoleArguments.php#L9

Answer (score 2):

You should use the getOpt function in PHP which supports short as well as long options in the command line:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php

From the link given above:

From the shell:

> php example.php -fvalue -h

Example:
$options = getopt("f:hp:");
var_dump($options);

This will print:
array(2) {
["f"]=>
string(5) "value"
["h"]=>
bool(false)
}